# Ramsey's Theorem

Tags: graph-theory

According to Ramsey’s Theorem, every graph of size $n$ contains either a complete subgraph (clique) of size $(\log n)=2$ or a set of independent points (anticlique) of size $(\log n)=2$ . We do not know, however, any better method of finding a complete subgraph than exhaustive search.

How would I go about describing an algorithm to find a clique of size $(\log n)/2$ in a graph of size $n$, doing and exhaustive search.

How would I calculate the number of steps?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First describe how to check if some $V'\subset V$ induces a complete graph and figure out the number of steps.  Then figure out how many $V'$ there are with $|V'| = (\log n)/2$.